# Optimize Kineticjs script that loads SVG and images

Tags: javascript, optimization, svg, kineticjs

I have a script that takes about 6 seconds to load. I want to know what I can do to make the load much faster. The script loads SVGdata first then function call to load images. Please take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/jacobsultd/9vam9n20/ and provide any direction. Secondary, what site can I use to track analyze web app loading time? Thanks.

The script is long and wont fit here. I build 3 container groups, put the images and control panels in each individually. The buttons are all created via for loops.

```
    var gpnl = new Kinetic.Group({x: 100,y: 400,draggable: true,width: 900,height: 50});



var cp1 = new Kinetic.Rect({x: 0,y: 0,stroke: 'black',width: 800,height: 500});



var complexText = new Kinetic.Text({x: s.getWidth() / 4,y: 10,text: '9Positions Glove Design Tool',fontSize: 30,fontFamily: font,fill: fontcolor,width: 500,padding: 10,align: 'center'});
gpnl.add(cp1);



var gt = new Kinetic.Text({x: 25,y: 10,text: 'Glove Type',fontSize: 16,fontFamily: font,fill: fontcolor,width: 300,padding: 2,align: 'left'});
gpnl.add(gt);

var gs = new Kinetic.Text({x: 300 - 40,y: 10,text: 'Glove Series',fontSize: 16,fontFamily: font,fill: fontcolor,width: 300,padding: 2,align: 'left'});
gpnl.add(gs);

var gthw = new Kinetic.Text({x: 575,y: 10,text: 'Throws',fontSize: 16,fontFamily: font,fill: fontcolor,width: 300,padding: 2,align: 'left'});gthw.nextX = 575;gthw.nextY = 38;
gpnl.add(gthw);

var gstl = new Kinetic.Text({x: 25,y: 75,text: 'Glove Back Style',fontSize: 16,fontFamily: font,fill: fontcolor,padding: 2,align: 'left'});
gpnl.add(gstl);

var ghnd = new Kinetic.Text({x: 300 - 40,y: 75,text: 'Hand Size',fontSize: 16,fontFamily: font,fill: fontcolor,padding: 2,align: 'left'});
gpnl.add(ghnd);


var gplm = new Kinetic.Text({x: 575,y: 75,text: 'Palm Protection',fontSize: 16,fontFamily: font,fill: fontcolor,width: 300,padding: 2,align: 'left'});
gpnl.add(gplm);

var gstf = new Kinetic.Text({x: 25,y: 165,text: 'Glove Stiffness',fontSize: 16,fontFamily: font,fill: fontcolor,width: 300,padding: 2,align: 'left'});
gpnl.add(gstf);

var gsze = new Kinetic.Text({x: 300 - 40,y: 165,text: 'Glove Size',fontSize: 16,fontFamily: font,fill: fontcolor,width: 300,padding: 2,align: 'left'});
gpnl.add(gsze);


var gfpro = new Kinetic.Text({x: 575,y: 165,text: 'Finger Protection',fontSize: 16,fontFamily: font,fill: fontcolor,width: 300,padding: 2,align: 'left'});
gpnl.add(gfpro);

var gweb = new Kinetic.Text({x: 25,y: 275,text: 'Click Web:',fontSize: 16,fontFamily: font,fill: fontcolor,width: 300,padding: 2,align: 'left'});
gpnl.add(gweb);

var dlmr = new Kinetic.Text({x: 25,y: 300,text: '(Web will not be reflected in design.)',fontSize: 12,fontFamily: font,fill: fontcolor,width: 300,padding: 2,align: 'left'});
gpnl.add(dlmr);


// Glove Parts SVG Graphics /////////////////////////////////////////////
var gp1 = new Kinetic.Group({x: 200,y: 50,draggable: true,width: 524,height: 350});   var lin = new Kinetic.Path({ id: 'lin', x: 57, y: 205, data: 'M 0,0 C 0,0 -2.667,10 -4.333,16.333 -6,22.667 -7.667,28 -3.667,33 c 4,5 8.334,8 18,10.333 9.667,2.334 43,7 51.334,7.667 8.333,0.667 26.333,2 33.666,1.667 7.334,-0.334 20,-3.334 25.334,-7 5.333,-3.667 11,-10.334 12,-15.667 1,-5.333 3,-13.667 0,-17.667 -3,-4 -18.334,-12 -27,-13.666 C 101,-3 76.333,-6 63,-5 49.667,-4 37.333,-4.333 25,-3.667 12.667,-3 0,0 0,0 Z', fill: 'black' });
```

-Andre

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the `Timeline` Tab in the `Chrome Developer tools` to figure out in which areas the time is really (Scripting,Loading etc.) spent.

I can see that you have complex SVG paths there. I am wondering if it would speed it up if you would reference them as "normal" svgs.

You can also make an `Audit` inside the `Chrome Developer` tools. I made some tests with your Fiddle.

It looks like most of the time is spent inside the kinetic `draw` function calls.

Is it possible to execute this function just once, after you instantiated all objects?

See also this link here, talking about batch draw: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-batch-draw/

Just found this:

> KineticJS is a fast, robust, HTML5 Canvas Library that is no longer
>   maintained

Comment: I know.. a mirror site still exists http://www.zeali.net/mirrors/html5canvastutorials/  and the docs http://agavestorm.com/kineticjs/.  I moved the svg load within the function that load images and load time down to 4.08 sec. I'll put in a loading gift and take away after loading. I can load an svg as a kinetic image, but not sure you can edit the fill once uploaded.

Comment: Would it be faster to use some library completely based on SVG? For me it looks like an application that could fit better in SVG only scenario. But I do not know if that has any impact on performance.

Comment: As KineticJS is no longer maintained you can use Konva. It is KineticJS fork. http://konvajs.github.io/

Comment: @Matthias there was an example in a post using fabricjs for svg using the kineticjs to manage canvas I will test, when I can find post again.  I will take a look at konvajs. Goto http://9positions.com/tool for the current finished product. Hit Next in first panel to the customization bit.